# Conditional exp. - $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$=$X$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I have very common task - 
Consider a probability space $\Omega$ with four elements a,b,c,d. Define $\sigma$-algebra $F$ on $\Omega$-collection of subsets of $\Omega$.

Probability measure by P{a}=1/6,  P{b}=1/3,  P{c}=1/4,  P{d}=1/4,
RV X,Y:

X{a}=1, X{b}=1, X{c}=-1, X{d}=-1,

Y{a}=1, Y{b}=-1, Y{c}=1, Y{d}=-1,

I need:

a)Derermine $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ and verify the partal averaging property.

b) Do thesame for $\mathbb{E}[Z|X]$, set $Z=X+Y$

с) Show that $\mathbb{E}[Z|X]$-$\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$=$X$

Here is my thoughts -

a) According to partal averaging property $\int_{[a,b]} \mathbb{E}[Y|X(w)]d\mathbb{P}(w) = \int_{[a,b]} Y(w)d\mathbb{P}(w)$ and $\int_{[c,d]} \mathbb{E}[Y|X(w)]d\mathbb{P}(w) = \int_{[c,d]} Y(w)d\mathbb{P}(w)$.

So for $\int_{[a,b]} Y(w)d\mathbb{P}(w)= Y(a)\mathbb{P}(a)+Y(b)\mathbb{P}(b)=-1/6$

$\mathbb{E}[Y|X](a)=-1/6*2/1=-1/3$, $\mathbb{E}[Y|X](b)=-1/6*2/1=-1/3$

$\int_{[a,b]} \mathbb{E}[Y|X(w)]d\mathbb{P}(w) = \mathbb{E}[Y|X](a)\mathbb{P}(a)+\mathbb{E}[Y|X](b)\mathbb{P}(b)$=-1/6

So for $\int_{[c,d]} Y(w)d\mathbb{P}(w)$= $Y(c)\mathbb{P}(c)+Y(d)\mathbb{P}(d)=0$

$\mathbb{E}[Y|X](c)$=$\mathbb{E}[Y|X](d)=0$

$\int_{[c,d]} \mathbb{E}[Y|X(w)]d\mathbb{P}(w) = \mathbb{E}[Y|X](c)\mathbb{P}(c)+\mathbb{E}[Y|X](d)\mathbb{P}(d)$=0

so averaging property is verified.

b) If I understand the logic right we have $Z(a)=2, Z(b)=0, Z(c)=0, Z(d)=-2$ and and  can calculate $\mathbb{E}[Z|X]$ the same way, but I feel that I am wrong.

c) I assume that it is necessary to use properties of conditional expectation here. I started like this - $\mathbb{E}[Z|X]$-$\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$=$\mathbb{E}[Z-[Y|X](liniarity)$=$\mathbb{E}[Z-Y]$ (take out known)

Can somebody be so kind as to check my thoughts and help me with c part? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, excellent first question. Shows that you've really put effort into the question prior to asking. Here's how to do (c) -- it's similar what you've done, but a bit cleaner. Also, you've got an additional expectation at the end that isn't supposed to be there.

$$E(Z|X) - E(Y|X) = E(Z-Y|X) = E(X|X) = X.$$

The first equality holds by linearity; the second is the definition of $Z$; the final is like the "take our known", as you said.

---

Note that there is a "sanity" check that you can do to see that your argument can't actually be right (these I often find are very helpful!). The LHS is a random variable, but the RHS is not (as an expectation of a random variable). For $\mathcal{F}$-measurable, bounded $R$, $E(RS \mid \mathcal{F}) = R E(S \mid \mathcal{F})$; in particular, taking $S = 1$ and $\mathcal{F} = \sigma(X)$ gives $E(R \mid R) = R$.

Hopefully this helps!